# C# Regex: finding all matches of a number of patterns

Tags: c#, regex

I need help with a Regular Expression in C# which identifies how many predefined 3-letter strings appear in a string.

So, for example:

```
Regex.Matches("qwerty", @"(?i)(qwe|wer|ert|rty|tyu|yui|uio|iop|op\[|p\[\])")
```

Would return:

```
["qwe", "wer", "ert", "rty"]
```

(But of course the Regex above is incorrect!).

FYI, this is to check whether 3 consecutive characters on a keyboard appear in a password (in the case above `"qwerty"` is the password.

Thanks :)

EDIT 1: This needs to be case-insensitive.

Comment: I don't know how much this matters to you, but even if you came up with a working RegEx, it still wouldn't cover non-US keyboards. For instance, even though it's based on the `qwerty` layout, to account for the Italian keyboard that I'm using, you would have to to include `opè`, `pè+`, `klò`, `òàù`, `m,.`, `,.-`, `P*é`, `Lç°`, `ç°§`, `NM;`, `M;:`, `;:_`. Another example would be the Slovenian keyboard, whose layout is `qwertZ` and hence would throw your RegEx off.

Comment: This isn't how regex works, and regex is not the best solution here.

Comment: @s.m. I agree that the whole premise of 3 consecutive letters on a keyboard as a password check is dumb. How do you cover a Chinese keyboard. However fixing up the given regex is at least possible.

Comment: @JGNI I'm 100% with you on that one, I just wanted to remind OP to consider localization issues in case they didn't :) Since it's password we're talking about, I didn't want them to be under the impression that they had a sure-fire way to secure against stupid ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead

```
Regex.Matches("qwerty",@"(?i)(?=(qwe|wer|ert|rty|tyu|yui|uio|iop|op\[|p\[\])).")
```

Comment: Good job using a regex as the OP asked, just beat me to it!

Comment: Yes, thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use US keyboard only (see s.m. comment) you can try *Linq* instead of *Regex*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

string source = "qwerty";

// either put chunks to test direct
string[] chunks = new string[] { 
  "qwe", "wer", "ert", "rty", "tuy", "yui", "uio", "iop", "op[", "p[]", "[]\\"};

// ...or generate them as 3-grams:
// string line = "qwertyuiop[]\\";
// string[] chunks = Enumerable
//   .Range(0, line.Length + 1 - 3)
//   .Select(start => line.Substring(start, 3))
//   .ToArray();

string[] appeared = chunks
  .Where(chunk => source.IndexOf(chunk, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
  .ToArray();

Console.Write(string.Join(", ", appeared));
```

**Outcome:**

```
qwe, wer, ert, rty
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Linq solution to achieve what I think you are looking for:

- We split the input in chunk of Length
- We check if our input contains any of the chunks

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KxExau)

```
public static bool ContainsAnySubstring(string predifined, int length, string input)
{
    var sections = predifined.Remove(predifined.Length - length + 1).Select((_,i) => predifined.Substring(i, length));
    return sections.Any(section => input.Contains(section));
}

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(ContainsAnySubstring("qwerty", 3, "azerty") == true);
    Console.WriteLine(ContainsAnySubstring("qwerty", 5, "azerty") == false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regex, you can just take every substrings of the input and check if it is a substring of your keyboard layout:

```
IEnumerable<string> FindContinuousKeyInputs(string input, int length = 3)
{
    if (length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(length));

    if (input.Length < length)
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();

    var rows = new string[]
    {
        @"qwertyuiop[]\",
        "asdfghjkl;'",
        "zxcvbnm,./"
    };

    return Enumerable.Range(0, input.Length - length + 1)
        .Select(x => input.Substring(x, length))
        .Where(x => rows.Any(y => y.Contains(x)));
}
```

For case insensitive, replace the last `Where` with this:

```
.Where(x => rows.Any(y => CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(y, x, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0));
```

Comment: Thanks, how might I make this case insensitive?

Comment: @JacobClayden I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)